# How to use messages included in sensor_msgs with ROSJava?

Tags: sensor-msgs, rosmake, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the project **sensor_msgs** from the repository:

```
roslocate info sensor_msgs
- svn:
        local-name: sensor_msgs
        uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_msgs/trunk/sensor_msgs
```

Before downloading this project in my worskspace, when rosmake detect the dependency:

```
<depend package="sensor_msgs" />
```

Shell printed the following message:

```
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
```

But later, when I download the project, I received the following message when I execute rosmake in my package:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
```

When I use messages from that package:

```
            Publisher<org.ros.message.sensor_msgs.JointState> motor =
                node.newPublisher("motor1", "sensor_msgs.JointState");
```

I receive the following exception when I execute the node:

```
Jan 8, 2012 10:59:22 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger fatal
SEVERE: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

But if I use messages from std_msgs, I don't have any problem:

```
            Publisher<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> publisher2 =
                node.newPublisher("motor1", "std_msgs/String");
```

How to use messages from sensor_msgs?

I noticed that the package sensor_msgs doesn't have any makefile to execute rosmake.

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12561/how-to-use-messages-included-in-sensor_msgs-with-rosjava?/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't have to explicitly install the sensor_msgs package; it should be part of your default ROS install, in the common_msgs stack. You're seeing errors because you have that package installed twice; I recommend you remove the copy that you manually installed.

You can confirm that you still have a valid install by running `roscd sensor_msgs` and observing that it finds the sensor_msgs package.

When passing the type string to newPublisher, they type is specified with a slash, as `sensor_msgs/JointState`, not `sensor_msgs.JointState`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1